# Unhealthy docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I’ve been struggling with an issue over the past few days. Specifically the unhealthy message I get for the Status of the clowder image. This fact does not allow me to run the application on localhost. Here is the result of `docker ps`

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                                                                  NAMES
d46319e43bd5        clowder/clowder:latest       "/bin/sh -c /home/cl…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours (unhealthy)   9000/tcp                                                               clowder_clowder_1
a1c4a3240a4a        clowder/monitor:latest       "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours               9999/tcp                                                               clowder_monitor_1
fa4e9662b1c8        traefik:1.7                  "/traefik --loglevel…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours               0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->443/tcp                            clowder_traefik_1
a59cf98c71c7        mongo:3.6                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours               27017/tcp                                                              clowder_mongo_1
5496405f71e7        elasticsearch:2              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours               9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                                     clowder_elasticsearch_1
7c2c986527d8        rabbitmq:management-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours               4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 15671-15672/tcp, 15691-15692/tcp, 25672/tcp   clowder_rabbitmq_1
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # SINGLE ENTRYPOINT
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # webserver to handle all traffic. This can use let's encrypt to generate a SSL cert.
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7
    command:
      - --loglevel=INFO
      - --api
      # Entrypoints
      - --defaultentrypoints=https,http
      - --entryPoints=Name:http Address::80 ${TRAEFIK_HTTP_REDIRECT:-""}
      - --entryPoints=Name:https Address::443 ${TRAEFIK_HTTPS_OPTIONS:-TLS}
      # Configuration for acme (https://letsencrypt.org/)
      - --acme=${TRAEFIK_ACME_ENABLE:-false}
      #- --acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      - --acme.email=${TRAEFIK_ACME_EMAIL:-""}
      - --acme.entrypoint=https
      - --acme.onhostrule=true
      - --acme.storage=/config/acme.json
      - --acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=http
      - --acme.storage=/config/acme.json
      - --acme.acmelogging=true
      # DOCKER
      - --docker=true
      - --docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - --docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --docker.watch=true
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - clowder
    ports:
      - "${TRAEFIK_HTTP_PORT-8000}:80"
      - "${TRAEFIK_HTTPS_PORT-8443}:443"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=${TRAEFIK_HOST:-}PathPrefixStrip: /traefik"
      - "traefik.website.frontend.whiteList.sourceRange=${TRAEFIK_IPFILTER:-172.16.0.0/12}"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - traefik:/config
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # CLOWDER APPLICATION
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # main clowder application
  clowder:
    image: clowder/clowder:${CLOWDER_VERSION:-latest}
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - clowder
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - CLOWDER_ADMINS=${CLOWDER_ADMINS:-admin@example.com}
      - CLOWDER_REGISTER=${CLOWDER_REGISTER:-false}
      - CLOWDER_CONTEXT=${CLOWDER_CONTEXT:-/}
      - CLOWDER_SSL=${CLOWDER_SSL:-false}
      - RABBITMQ_URI=${RABBITMQ_URI:-amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq/%2F}
      - RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE=${RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE:-clowder}
      - RABBITMQ_CLOWDERURL=${RABBITMQ_CLOWDERURL:-http://clowder:9000}
      - SMTP_MOCK=${SMTP_MOCK:-true}
      - SMTP_SERVER=${SMTP_SERVER:-smtp}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=clowder"
      - "traefik.port=9000"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=${TRAEFIK_HOST:-}PathPrefix: ${CLOWDER_CONTEXT:-/}"
    volumes:
      - clowder-custom:/home/clowder/custom
      - clowder-data:/home/clowder/data
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # CLOWDER DEPENDENCIES
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # database to hold metadata (required)
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - clowder
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
  # message broker (optional but needed for extractors)
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - clowder
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS=-rabbitmq_management path_prefix "/rabbitmq"
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER:-guest}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS:-guest}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=rabbitmq"
      - "traefik.port=15672"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=${TRAEFIK_HOST:-}PathPrefix: /rabbitmq"
      - "traefik.website.frontend.whiteList.sourceRange=${TRAEFIK_IPFILTER:-172.16.0.0/12}"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
  # search index (optional, needed for search and sorting future) 
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:2
    command: elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name="clowder"
    networks:
      - clowder
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - cluster.name=clowder
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  # monitor clowder extractors
  monitor:
    image: clowder/monitor:${CLOWDER_VERSION:-latest}
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - clowder
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_URI=${RABBITMQ_URI:-amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq/%2F}
      - RABBITMQ_MGMT_PORT=15672
      - RABBITMQ_MGMT_PATH=/rabbitmq
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=monitor"
      - "traefik.port=9999"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=${TRAEFIK_FRONTEND_RULE:-}PathPrefixStrip:/monitor"
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# NETWORK FOR CONTAINER COMMUNICATION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
networks:
  clowder:
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# VOLUMES FOR PERSISTENT STORAGE
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
volumes:
  traefik:
  clowder-data:
  clowder-custom:
  mongo:
  rabbitmq:
  elasticsearch:
```

I run `docker-compose up -d` to create the app. The problem started after upgrading to macos 10.15.7. Before that I was able to run things smoothly. I’m sorry but I only have limited experience with docker. Thank you in advance y’all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is to change the `healthchech.sh` file inside the clowder container to:

```
#!/bin/bash

### Add trailing backslash if not in context

[[ "${CLOWDER_CONTEXT}" != */ ]] && CLOWDER_CONTEXT="${CLOWDER_CONTEXT}/"
curl -s --fail http://localhost:9000${CLOWDER_CONTEXT:-/}healthz || exit 1
```

And problem solved.